# How to single-object prelink a framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-linking

My situation:

- I am developing a dynamically linked framework called `A`, wrapped into `.xcframework`
- I depend upon other frameworks `B` and `C` that are linked **statically**
- However, I don't want the consumers of `A` to learn about the existence of `B` and `C`
- And because of this, I would like to perform single object pre-link during the linkage of `A` so that `B` and `C` are totally consumed by `A` and are to be never seen again.

This task would be relatively easy if instead of static frameworks (`.framework`), I used static libraries (`.a`). In this case, I would be able to easily plop the path to the `.a` into the `Prelink Libraries` setting, set `Perform Single-Object Prelink` to `YES`, disable the embedding - and the goal would be accomplished.

However, I am facing the linkage against frameworks, not libs. The problem is that it has resources and bundles inside of it.

- If I put a path to the `.xcframework` or `.framework` into the `Prelink Libraries` Build Setting, the build fails:

```
Command MasterObjectLink failed with a nonzero exit code
can't map file, errno=22 file '/Users/*****/B/B.xcframework/ios-arm64/B.framework'
```

- And if I put a path to the actual executable inside the framework (`B.xcframework/ios-arm64/B.framework/B`), the build succeeds. However, none of the resources of `B.framework` are present in the resulting output.

Is there a way to automatically copy resources during `Single-Object Prelink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to automatically copy the resources if the regular `Embed Frameworks` isn't used.